# Date plotting seems to be broken in dash plotting framework

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I'm trying to plot a horizontal bar chart in the dash environment, however whilst I can plot elements such as days, or numbers, I cannot get the correct range. In order words the start date is correct but the end date is not correct.

```
def build_data(contract_name, stream): # one stream only
    data = []
    month_list = sorted([z['month'] for z in stream['monthList']])
    month_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(month, '%Y-%m-%d') for month in month_list]
    print month_list

    min_month = min(month_list)
    max_month = max(month_list)

    start = go.Bar(x=[min_month], y=[contract_name], orientation = 'h', marker=dict(color='rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)'))
    end = go.Bar(x=[max_month], y=[contract_name], orientation = 'h', marker=dict(color='rgba(55, 128, 191, 0.7)', 
        line=dict( color='rgba(55, 128, 191, 1.0)', width=2,)))
    data.append(start)
    data.append(end)
    return data


def plot_bar(data):
    app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children=''), html.Div(children='''History.'''),

    dcc.Graph(
        figure=go.Figure(
        data = data,
        layout=go.Layout(title='', showlegend=False, barmode='stack', margin=go.Margin(l=200, r=0, t=40, b=20))),
    style={'height': 300},
    id='my-graph')
    ])      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = build_data('xxx', example_stream)
    plot_bar(data)
    print data
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And the input data:

```
example_stream={'status': 'active', 'monthList': [{'month': '2017-04-01'}, {'month': '2017-06-01'}]}
```

The most important aspect is there are two dates: '2017-05-01' and '2017-04-01', converted to python date object. However the lower bound is plotted, but the ending bar ends up way off at some time in the future.

I checked these routines with non date data and it behaved as expected.

I put the chart here below:[image: Horizontal axis is way off]

Comment: **Item weight  center and the link between the item location cannot be relative !** All positions must be absolute values. Just the dimensions of the item/stage can be dynamic. Another point use `canvas.js`.

Comment: @dsgdfg, Yes the date data that goes in both is absolute dates. No relativity between the dates.

Comment: Please update your code with some comment showing "stream" content dict or at least "stream['monthList']" content . thanks

Comment: @ASTEFANI Added the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the second date should be a timedelata, rather than a datetime.  Internally Python's datetime objects are referenced to Jan 1 1970 (see [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).  So that is about 47 years ago.  The difference between the start and end of your bar looks to be on this order, so I think it is interpreting the end date wrong.

Perhaps try:

```
max_month = max(month_list) - min_month
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but failed to plot anything.

Comment: If I try this approach, I get the following error on screen and no plot: `Error loading layout` which stems from: `TypeError: datetime.timedelta(61) is not JSON serializable`